# QTableWidget Item Get Widget Type and Access It

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I am attempting to sum rows in a QtableWidget and I get a segmentation fault when doing so not sure what is causing this, but I think it has something to do with the fact that I am setting the cell widget items as spinboxes and I am not accessing them correctly.
I also am unable to get the totalRow function to fire when the spin box changes, when I set it in the cellChanged event.

totalRow Function (Supposed To Total The Row When A Cell Is Changed)

```
int MainWindow::totalRow(int srow)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int num_col = ui->tblScores->columnCount();
    int num_row = ui->tblScores->rowCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < num_col - 1 ; ++j) {
            QTableWidgetItem *tableItem = ui->tblScores->item(srow,j);

            sum += tableItem->text().toInt();
            cout << sum << endl;
        }
        QTableWidgetItem *tableItem = new QTableWidgetItem;
        tableItem->setText(QString::number(sum));
        ui->tblScores->setItem(srow,num_col - 1,tableItem);
    return sum;
}
```

setupTable Function (This is what sets the table items to spinboxes)

```
void MainWindow::setupTable()
{
    int num_col = ui->tblScores->columnCount();
    int num_row = ui->tblScores->rowCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_col - 1 ; ++j) {
            ui->tblScores->setCellWidget(i,j,new QSpinBox(ui->tblScores));
        }
        ui->tblScores->setCellWidget(i,num_col - 1,new QLabel(ui->tblScores));
    }
}
```

cellChanged Event

```
void MainWindow::on_tblScores_cellChanged(int row, int column)
{
    totalRow(row);
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to call `cellWidget()` and cast it to QSpinBox to get the value of your cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution with cellWidget as suggested above.

```
int MainWindow::totalRow(int srow)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int num_col = ui->tblScores->columnCount();
        for(int j = 0; j < num_col - 1 ; j++) {
            QSpinBox* sp;
            sp = (QSpinBox*)ui->tblScores->cellWidget(srow,j);
            sum = sum + sp->value();
        }
        QTableWidgetItem *tableItem = new QTableWidgetItem;
        tableItem->setText(QString::number(sum));
        ui->tblScores->setItem(srow,num_col - 1,tableItem);
    return sum;
}
```